# How to add an GUI component like a Button in a Editor?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm a beginner in RCP just started building RCP application today.I want to a GUI component like a Button ,comboBox,Checkbox in a Editor .I've managed to add a editor in Extensions and create a class for it.I have written the code to create a label in creatPartControl but it does not work..I get a black window.Should I add the editor in perspective  like this

```java
layout.addStandaloneView(Editor.id, true, IPageLayout.TOP,0.7f,
                layout.getEditorArea());
layout.addStandaloneView(View.ID, true, IPageLayout.BOTTOM,0.4f,
                layout.getEditorArea());
```

Please help me resolve this issue.If possible please give an eg on how to add a editor and create a label and a button in it.
Thank you for your help in advance
code in my Editor.java content in `createPartControl()`

```java
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());
Button b=new Button(parent,SWT.TOGGLE);

b.setText("Hello ");
Label label1 = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
label1.setText("First Name");


package com.hello;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorSite;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart;

public class Editor extends EditorPart {
    public static final String ID = "TestApplication.editor3";

    public Editor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doSaveAs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
            throws PartInitException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDirty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("sssssss");
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Add the code from `createPartControl`

Comment: When you say you get a black window, do you mean your editor opens but shows only black content, or your entire application window is black?

Comment: no i have a view  along with it..the view is displayed corretly.but there is a area like a window it has maximise and minimise option.

Comment: Can you post more of your editor class (maybe all of it), which class does it extend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly initializing the editor and it causes problems when opening the editor. Fill up your `init()` method like below and see if this helps:

```java
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
        throws PartInitException {
    setSite(site);
    setInput(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I worked on an Eclipse editor.  Here's a screen capture of the editor so you can see I did more than add a Button.

[image: Cobol editor]

- I extended the Viewer class to create the GUI of the editor.
- I extended the EditorPart class to create the functionality of the editor.

Because of the kind of editor I was building, I had to create my own version of Canvas and my own version of IDocument.